# Reverse quantile for scores in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to ranks quantiles for my data, but I get the high rank for the highest score. I want to get the lowest rank (i.e., 1) for the highest score.

The following code gives me a high rank for the highest score, which I am not interested in:

```
M %>%
    mutate(quantile = ntile(Score, 10))
```

I have used reverse= TRUE, or include.lowest = TRUE, did not work. Can you help me? I felt that it is not necessary to provide a sample of data.

Comment: ```M %>%
    mutate(quantile = ntile(-Score, 10))```

Comment: At the top of the docs for `ntile`: "All ranking functions map smallest inputs to smallest outputs. Use desc() to reverse the direction."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just negate the values:

```r
M %>% mutate(quantile = ntile(-Score, 10))
```

***Example:***

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(-score, 3))

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   ntile date        score quantile
#   <int> <date>      <dbl>    <int>
# 1     1 2005-08-31 -2.39         3
# 2     1 2005-09-30  0.573        2
# 3     1 2005-10-31 -1.61         3
# 4     1 2005-11-30  5.43         1
# 5     1 2005-12-31  0.106        2
# 6     1 2006-01-31  6.66         1
```

***Toy Data:***

```r
df1 <- structure(list(ntile = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                      date = structure(c(13026, 13056, 13087, 13117, 13148, 13179), 
                                       class = "Date"), 
                      score = c(-2.38916419707325, 0.572675136581781, -1.61130358515631, 
                                 5.42706994951004, 0.105533424368025, 6.65697289481407)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```